# user class authenticate NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nomethoderror

In a sample login program , I have two classes. Sessions and user. The user table has two field name, password. The sessions methods continue to get 'NoMethodError' when calling the authenticate method of the user class.

THe user class looks like follows:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @user = User.find(:first, :order => 'RANDOM()')
  end

  def show
   @user = User.find(:all)
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
   #redirect_to user_path
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])
    @user.save
    #redirect_to 'http://localhost:3000/user/show'
  end


  def self.authenticate( password)
    #user = User.find_by_name(name)

    if user.find_by_password(password)#match_password(password)
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

 def self.match_password(password="")
   encrypted_password == BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(password, salt)
 end  
end
```

The sessions class had the create method, that calls the user's authenticate fn.
Here is the create methohd

```
def create
   user = User.find_by_name(params[:session][:name].downcase)

   if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
     # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page.
     sign_in user
     redirect_to user
   else
     flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination' # Not quite right!
     render 'new'
   end
end
```

Here is the stack

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at Sun Sep 30 15:21:02 -0400 2012
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Sign in", "session"=>{"name"=>"ar", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "authenticity_token"=>"vxYHw/4JV2fJuvvBN4GVLv31aBl8ETEtQPBB/483q/Q=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."name" = 'ar' LIMIT 1
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `authenticate' for #<User:0xb69650e4>):
  app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:10:in `create'
```

Thanks in Advance,
A.

Comment: You seem to have mixed up the controller code for `UserController` with the model code for `User`.

Comment: Right, put self.authenticate and self.match_password into the User < ActiveRecord::Base class.

Answer (score 0):

This block should be in your User model not in UserController:

```
def self.authenticate( password)
  #user = User.find_by_name(name)

  if user.find_by_password(password)#match_password(password)
    return true
  else
    return false
  end
end
```

The reason being that you want to call `.authenticate` on an instance of a User object, which is something that happens in the model.

Functions in the controller are generally used for serving requests, eg in response to someone visiting a URL on your app like `/users/123/authenticate` (which isn't what you want in this case).

Comment: So how do you compare the provided password and the hashed one in the database?

Comment: If you're working on something new, you might want to look at `has_secure_password` instead of the above -- this RailsCast is a great intro: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1